# Traversing through a tree (multi nest)

Tags: python, json, for-loop, recursion, arraylist

There is a parent, children, grandchildren and many more relationship like the json given below (`id`'s are unique inside each list), if the nesting is up to 10 levels with each level having different lengths. What is the best way to find a `uni_code` to insert another object (child) into its list?

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "status": "active",
  "created": "",
  "children": [{
      "id": "1",
      "status": "active",
      "created": "",
      "children": [{
          "id": "1",
          "status": "active",
          "created": "",
          "children": [{
              "id": "1",
              "status": "active",
              "created": "",
              "children": [

              ],
              "uni_code": "EGCFJ1"
            },
            {
              "id": "1",
              "status": "active",
              "created": "",
              "children": [

              ],
              "uni_code": "D356RY"
            },

          ],
          "uni_code": "EGCFJ1"
        },


      ],
      "uni_code": "Y7TUP8"
    },


    {
      "id": "4",
      "status": "active",
      "created": "",
      "children": [

      ],
      "uni_code": "WA1JNS"
    },


         ],
  "uni_code": "I429TD"
}
```

Comment: What have you tried already, what are your thoughts?

Comment: An option would be to loop over all the elements in every level.

Comment: solution by @martineau worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Based on your follow-on question in a comment, I believe I now understand what your were asking…and have updated my answer accordingly.*

Often you can traverse a recursive data-structure like a tree by using a function that calls itself recursively.

What I mean:

```
def insert_into_tree(tree, new_child, target):
    if tree['uni_code'] == target:
        tree['children'].append(new_child)
        return True
    for child in tree['children']:
        if insert_into_tree(child, new_child, target):
            return True
    return False  # `target` not found.


data = {
    "id": "1",
    "status": "active",
    "created": "",
    "children": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "status": "active",
            "created": "",
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": "1",
                    "status": "active",
                    "created": "",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "id": "1",
                            "status": "active",
                            "created": "",
                            "children": [],
                            "uni_code": "EGCFJ1"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "1",
                            "status": "active",
                            "created": "",
                            "children": [],
                            "uni_code": "D356RY"
                        }
                    ],
                    "uni_code": "EGCFJ1"
                }
            ],
            "uni_code": "Y7TUP8"
        },
        {
            "id": "4",
            "status": "active",
            "created": "",
            "children": [],
            "uni_code": "WA1JNS"
        }
    ],
    "uni_code": "I429TD"
}


new_object = {
    "id": "1",
    "status": "active",
    "created": "",
    "children": [],
    "uni_code": "THX1138"
}

target = "EGCFJ1"
if insert_into_tree(data, new_object, target):
    print(f'new child added to {target!r}')
else:
    print(f'{target!r} not found, new child not added')
```

Comment: is there a way to use the above function to create a new child inside any uni_code ?

Comment: my use case is simple, I am using Django with Postgres(JSONField), I need to maintain a tree for all the objects, and update it when a new child is created or deleted it when the child is removed. So, every time I add a new child I need a whole tree with the new child updated. if I use the above function, it only gives the child and its immediate parent and not the whole tree. Any solution?

Comment: If you add `import json` followed by `print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))` after calling the `insert_into_tree()` currently shown in my answer, you will see that it, in fact, updated the whole tree.